# How to create my own ListFragment in Android?

Tags: android, list, listview, row, android-listfragment

In a normal ListView, I can  usually create my own style for a single row.

How can I do it when I have a ListFragment?

I know that I have to change the second parameter in this line:

`setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items))`;

But, what if the single row has more than three values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `getListView()` inside a `ListFragment` you'll get the corresponding `ListView` returned and can do whatever you want with it.

Regarding your second question: 
If you want to control the behaviour of the adapter just build your own custom adapter. 
It requires a little work the first time but you'll need and use it a lot, once you learned how to do it.

There are a lot of tutorials out there about this, e.g. [this one](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html). 
Be sure to also use the holder pattern for optimized performance.

The result could look like this

```
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(itemList, context);
...
getListView().setListAdapter(adapter);
```